# Декомпиляция кода на Scala

Tags: компиляция, scala, декомпиляция

Есть эзотерический код написанный на Scala с большим количеством стримов и лямбда выражений, его нужно переписать другой язык программирования.

Появилась идея декомпилировать код Scala в более простую форму, c более простым синтаксисом, без всяких стримов и лямбда выражений, чтобы было легче его понимать. Есть ли  утилиты которые позволяют это сделать? Я знаю, что есть команда `scalac -Xprint:parse`, которая компилирует и в то же время выводит в консоль код в более простой форме, но скопировав и вставив этот код, выводит кучу ошибок, которых я не понимаю, так как не изучал язык программирования Scala. Есть идеи?

Comment: А какой будет смысл в коде, сгенерированном какой-то тузлой, если в том коде никто ничего не разберет? Учите теперь основы скалы, по-другому нормально сделать не получится

Comment: Zergatul, да там не  только основы изучать придется, там конструкции,  которых в интернете не найдешь.

Comment: Почему в интернете не найдешь? Навряд ли там в коде какие-то недокументированные фичи языка.

Comment: Можно декомпилировать в Джаву, но понять результат будет еще сложнее.